# NET 5 and EF: how to use AddPooledDbContextFactory in liu of DbContext in services

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I recently came across `AddPooledDbContextFactory` concept as part of my NET 5 self-education piece and am keen to implement it properly. However, I am not sure how to use it with generics that I generally use.

Example of my current setup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
        services.AddDbContext<TestDbContext>(
                (s, o) => o.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseConnection"))
                           .UseLoggerFactory(s.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>()));

// other code //
    }
```

my repository generic:

```
    public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T
    {
        private readonly TestDbContext _dbContext;
        public Repository(TestDbContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }
        

        public async Task Create(T entity)
        {
           await _dbContext.Set<T>().AddAsync(entity);
           await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        // other methods //
   }
```

this is invoked in following manner as example:

```
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    
    private readonly IRepository<Test> testRepo;

    public WeatherForecastController(IRepository<Test> testRepo)
    {
        this.testRepo= testRepo;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>> GetAsync()
    {
        await testRepo.Create(new Test { Name = "Superman" });
        
        // other code
    }

}
```

I would like to convert this to use the new AddPooledDbContextFactory concept but cannot find enough documentation to figure out how to do this.

Atm only thing that comes to mind is using statements at each method but that doesn't make sense.

Any advice on this?

Comment: Entity framework is *already* an implementation of the repository pattern. By double abstracting it into another repository you can certainly make things more difficult than they need to be. Just inject the context or factory into your controller. Easy.

Comment: I would argue, why? why do you want to change this from your current implementation, and before you say what i think you are... please double check that, contexts are already pooled unless you said not to, but default is to.., aka ur letting Di manage ur instance, an your letting ef manage the pooling so leave as is.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 altho i agree and disagree, with your comment, many ways to do "repository" pattern if your just wrapping it the same way then yeah sure, " double abstracting" is pointless, but i do think that is a separate conversation. why you would want to inject a context factory over the default Di life management and pooling, im leaning towards that if your not in a "request" life time scope and something else then maybe.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 and @Seabizkit, you are both way off base in your comments. In fact, I would delete all of them.

@pinkfloydx33, the simplest thing I can say about your repository pattern comment is that, what you are suggesting is for the OP to put all their queries & logic into their controller class. That is not a good strategy for writing loosely coupled and maintainable code.

@Seabizkit, there's a difference between ASP.NET DI service lifetime and `DbContext` pooling.  See my answer below for more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Documentation is not yet complete and is in progress, you track this issue
https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/2523

You can also a look at the tests for `AddPooledDbContextFactory` to see how to register `DbContext` with
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/search?q=AddPooledDbContextFactory

for example to register DbContext:

```
services.AddPooledDbContextFactory<TContext>(ob =>
    ob.UseSqlServer("ConnectionString").EnableServiceProviderCaching(false), poolSize: 32)
```

Then in your class, inject an `IDbContextFactory<TContext>` and use it like this:

```cs
using(var context = _factory.CreateDbContext())
{
    var orders = await context.Orders.Where(o => o.Id > 3).ToListAsync();
}
```

According to [this post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-entity-framework-core-ef-core-5-0-preview-7/#dbcontextfactory):

> Note that the DbContext instances created in this way are not managed
> by the application's service provider and therefore must be disposed
> by the application

You can also check out this post to see how to use `IDbContextFactory`:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-server-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Probably worth noting that the context should be disposed when you're done with it, so in your example showing the instantiation of the DbContext it should really be `using (var context = _factory.CreateDbContext()) { ... }`. This might be obvious information for those familiar with EF Core but not everyone.

Comment: Good point @Lulke but the question has `asp.net-core` tag and I assumed the questioner uses `AddPooledDbContextFactory` inside ASP.NET Core application and at end of the request `context` will be disposed without the need to use `using` statement.

Comment: I'm not so sure, from Microsoft's announcement of EF Core 5:
"Note that the DbContext instances created in this way are not managed by the application's service provider and therefore must be disposed by the application..."

Source: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-entity-framework-core-ef-core-5-0-preview-7/#dbcontextfactory

Comment: could you explain the benefits of doing this as i can not see it, maybe a MS doc which explains in more detail.

Comment: @Seabizkit check this out. It uses Blazor as an example but there are other use cases. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor

Comment: thanks so my comment above on OP question are even more valid https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#implicitly-sharing-dbcontext-instances-via-dependency-injection

Comment: Is the using statement necessary? I think especially in the"Pooled" DbContextFactory is managing the disposal and reuse of DbContext itself.

Comment: @cpt.oneeye I think you missed this quote `Note that the DbContext instances created in this way are not managed by the application's service provider and therefore must be disposed by the application`

Answer (score 2):

@Aeseir your code looks good to me.  You are following best practices and you don't *need* to change it.

You are using the Repository Pattern, so your Repository class has all of your query logic which helps create loosely coupled and maintainable code.

In your `ConfigureServices`, calling: `services.AddDbContext<TestDbContext>()` registers `TestDbContext` with `Scoped` service lifetime.  This is the way that `DbContext` is designed to work, and it will also work well with ASP.NET controllers, since they have a `Scoped` lifetime as well.

You did not show your code for registering `IRepository`, but that service lifetime should be `Scoped` as well.  Btw, you can tell `BuildServiceProvider()` to validate scope registrations:

```
builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider(validateScopes: true);
```

Since `DbContext` is designed to have a `Scoped` service lifetime, and since your `IRepository` and `Controller` services are `Scoped` as well, every request gets brand new:

1. `Controller`
2. `IRepository`
3. `DbContext`

Those services are used for the request and then `Diposed`.  This is how ASP.NET is intended to work.

Apparently at some point, **DbContext pooling** has been introduced to improve performance.  In this case, EF Core manages a pool of context instances for you and *resets* them after each request.  This can improve performance, although in some situations, the benefit might be small.  See [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/advanced-performance-topics) for more details.

I think for use with ASP.NET controllers (i.e. the code you posted above) all you need to do to take advantage of EF Core context pooling is call `AddDbContextPool()`:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContextPool<ApplicationDbContext>(/* ... */);
```

However, if you needed to use `DbContext` in services registered with `Singleton` lifetime, then the pattern above would not work well.  Because when a `Scoped` service gets used in a `Singleton` service, the `Scoped` service is essentially a `Singleton`.  Each request would not get a new `DbContext`, nor a reset one from the pool.  **(See QUESTION below.)**

In that case, you might want to use the [`DbContext` factory pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor) instead:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>(/* ... */);
```

Or, if you want to use [context pooling with a factory pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/advanced-performance-topics?tabs=with-di%2Cwith-constant#managing-state-in-pooled-contexts):

```
builder.Services.AddPooledDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>(/* ... */);
```

The `DbContextFactory` can then be used in other services through constructor injection. For example:

```
private readonly IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> _contextFactory;

public MyController(IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> contextFactory)
{
    _contextFactory = contextFactory;
}
```

The injected factory can then be used to construct `DbContext` instances in the controller code. For example:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    using (var context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext())
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that when you call `CreateDbContext()`, context instances are not managed by the service provider and therefore must be disposed by the application.  Hence you need to `Dispose` of them yourself, such as in the example above which does so with the `using` statement.

**QUESTION**

I am doing my best to understand this stuff and explain it, but I might be wrong, so please call out an inaccuracies in my post.

**When using `AddDbContextPool()`, does the `DbContext` get registered as a `Singleton` or `Scoped`?**

I found in [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/advanced-performance-topics?tabs=with-di%2Cwith-constant#managing-state-in-pooled-contexts) *that it's effectively registered as a Singleton*:

> Context pooling works by reusing the same context instance across requests; this means that it's effectively registered as a Singleton, and the same instance is reused across multiple requests (or DI scopes). This means that special care must be taken when the context involves any state that may change between requests.

However, I have found that if `AddDbContextPool()` is used along with `true` for `validatedScopes`:

```
builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider(validateScopes: true)
```

When `DbContext` is consumed from another service which is registered as a `Singleton`, the following exception is thrown:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot consume scoped service 'ApplicationDbContext' from singleton 'IRepository'.'

Hence why I stated above that `DbContext` still gets `Scoped` service lifetime.

Comment: A pooled DBContext is reused across multiple requests... but not concurrently, the scoped provider controls when it can be released.

So it had a quasi-singleton object lifetime, but it's Scoped in it's usage and resolution.

If you use the factory, then the factory is the one that service provider notifies when the scope has completed.  I believe under the hood, this is the way it works regardless of whether you inject the DbCntext or DbContextFactory.  The Factory just allows you to defer ( or never! ) the creation of the scope's DbContext instance